# Install YII2 on Centos 7

Tags: frameworks, centos, installation, yii2

I read that it was impossible to install yii2 on a standard hosting platform (redhat, centos...) without deleting the AssetManager.
And install is lock with it. Access refused, permission denied.... Despite the rights 777 on the assets folder.

And in default way, hack code, disable control like (is_writable) to allow continued the install process to congratulation, but without css ....
But I can't modify all the code , to use it?

They're a lot of issue about assetmanager.

I tried yii1 few years ago, and it was wonderful framework... But everything is permitted under windows. Someone tried to install it under redhat, fedora, Centos.

There is a specific configuration ... Or yii2 not builted and designed for theses environments ?
Because i found tuto about laravel 5.1, Zend 2 since 2013... But nothing about Yii2, and only one... about Yii1... on this hosting OS.

Yii2 is ready for professionnel standard hosting environnement or is just for hobbist with Wamp under Windows ? (Online tuto is in majority on this OS, with Wamp...).

And maybe for that, it's work fine... like i test under windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the links. I had read
Finally I found the answer, which is never explained in the tutorial above (because often disabled and the module is not present in Ubuntu or Debian)

It's SELinux security. To install Yii2 there are the following commands:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t 'each folder writable'
setsebool -P httpd_unified 1
```

Without this open rignt, you can't install Yii2

Answer (score 0):

All what Yii 2.0 requires is a Web server supporting PHP 5.4 or above.
( *currently not PHP 7 due to [reserved word conflict that will be solved in future releases](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7936)* )

And yes 5 stables versions ready for production has been released, currently [Yii 2.0.5](http://www.yiiframework.com/news/87/yii-2-0-5-is-released-security-fix/)

Here is a quick example about [how to install Yii2 with CentOS6](http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-Yii-Frameworks-with-CentOS-6)                which has nothing different from what is already described in the [official docs.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html)

If you know any CentOS related issue please post them and we will discuss answers, because sincerely i just did few searches and didn't found any besides few wrong apache or nginx configurations or missing packages like [this CentoOS7 case](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/60564-problem-when-installing-yii2-app-basic/). Otherwise if you need a pre-configured & working VM with Yii2 and CentOS 7, then you may check this [vagrant repo.](https://github.com/agounaris/vagrant-centos7-lamp-es-redis)